# Access SQL Server database on another computer

Tags: sql-server

I have created a little tool, which lets me write some data into a database.

This database is located on my laptop and as of until now, that tool was only able to locally access the database. I now need my friend to be able to use that tool to connect to my database from his own PC.

I've read about port-forwarding, opening the firewall, etc., but I've never really gotten the hang of it.

This is what I currently have:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=admin;" + 
                                   "password=password;server=myDatabase;" + 
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + 
                                   "database=database; " + 
                                   "connection timeout=30");
```

And of course, the usual procedure:

```
try
{
    myConnection.Open();
    //Do Stuff
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Note: I don't really care much about security, since the usage of this tool is only temporary and I doubt that anyone would try to "break in".

Comment: Is this an **Express** edition of SQL Server? That edition - by default - doesn't support remote connections - you have to explicitly enable that feature in order to use it

Comment: @marc_s Yes, it is. How do I enable that feature?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look upon [activating Remote connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) to your SQL Server Instance. As already mentioned, they will not work on Express editions, but since your project is temporary, you may install a [trial](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2014) (lasts for 180 days).

Comment: Thank you. I guess I have to install the trial. Given that I use the port 1433, to what would I have to change "server=myDatabase;"? Would that be the external IP and the Port 1433, I guess?

Comment: server is full path to your instance. E.g: hostname\SQLSERVER2014. Port 1433 is the default one, so it is ok if you do not specify it. So, pay attention to what is your instance name when installing SQL Server (you may leave it as default instance/unnamed, if it will be the only one on that machine).

Comment: Would that still work, even if he'd try to connect from an entirely different network?

Comment: In order to access your SQL instance across the Internet, you must have connectivity. That means that you can access SqlServerMachine:1433. This can checked in Windows using telnet SqlServerMachine 1433 (requires telnet client to be installed). If machine is behind a router/firewall, we are talking about network configuration changes (firewall rule, router port forwarding etc.)

Comment: So additionally to those firewall rules, I have to do port forwarding on my router? My router is a fritzbox and when I want to port-forward something, I get several options like "FTP-Server", "HTTP-Server", "EMule-TCP", "Exposed Host", etc. Do you happen to know the most valid option to choose from?